# Using ReactQuery gathered data to create a simple Item List and Item Details application

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-query

I'm trying to learn how React Query works with a GraphQL API and have currently built a small application to do so. I'll explain what I'm currently doing and what I would like to achieve.

Current scenario:

- I perform a request to a GraphQL API on the App component.
- ItemList component that lists the items I got from the API

What I would like to achieve:

- No more requests to the API, just use the data I already got
- Add navigation to the ItemList component
- Create an ItemDetails component that you navigate to by clicking on an item on ItemList , which has more details for each item (I already have these extra details from the first request)
- On the ItemDetails component, I have a Next and a Previous button to navigate to another item.

Conceptually, I'm not sure how to achieve the results I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only point react-query related here would be:

> No more requests to the API, just use the data I already got

To achieve that, you can set a `staleTime: Infinity` on your query. It will make sure that once data is fetched, it is always considered fresh, which means no background updates.

From there on, `useQuery` will give you an Array of Items. You can render your list, when clicking on an Item you render the Details component and pass the item to it. `Next` and `Previous` button control state on the parent component, which contains the currently selected item to display. This is 100% the same approach as if the ItemList data would be client state.

---

Alternatively, you *can* spawn up a separate `useQuery` on the detail page, which uses the list query + the `select` option to pick the correct Item from the list, but the biggest advantage of that approach is that you will get background refetches once a stale query mounts - which is what you *don't* want as you stated in the question.